# Trying to change img src via switch

Tags: jquery, image, switch-statement, overlay, src

I got three images on my page and I want to display them in classic overlay if they are clicked. I got problems with changing source of the image in overlay.

I'm firstly storing the image index in variable and im trying to change the source via swich which is chcecking image index.

But somehow it doesn't work and I would like to ask you why, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
$("#imageholder img").click(function(){ //checking if was clicked on img from #imageholder
var imageId = $("#imageholder img").index(this); //store imageID of cliced image into variable
alert(imageId); // alert imageId (debugging)
var overlayImage = $("#overlay-image");
// Adding img elements to overlay div based on imageId
switch (imageId) {
  case "0":
   overlayImage.src='img/1.jpg';
   break;
   case "1":
   overlayImage.src='img/2.jpg';
   break;
   case "2":
   overlayImage.src='img/3.jpg';
   break;
   default:
   alert("No imge was loaded");
}
function on() {
document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}

on();

});
});
```

Comment: Check my answer. It should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your switch case must have integer value as they are referencing the index value of image and index are integer type so change

```
switch (imageId) {
  case "0":
   overlayImage.src='img/1.jpg';
   break;
   case "1":
   overlayImage.src='img/2.jpg';
   break;
   case "2":
   overlayImage.src='img/3.jpg';
   break;
   default:
   alert("No imge was loaded");
}
```

to

```
switch (imageId) {
  case 0:
   overlayImage.src='img/1.jpg';
   break;
   case 1:
   overlayImage.src='img/2.jpg';
   break;
   case 2:
   overlayImage.src='img/3.jpg';
   break;
   default:
   alert("No imge was loaded");
}
```

Comment: But the OP want to get the index of the element from the array of the element.

Comment: First comment in proper english. You are not clear with what you mean.

Comment: `$("#imageholder img").indexOf(this);` this syntax was not a correct one.you are combaining `jquery` object with `js` https://fiddle.jshell.net/gcoq0d8r/1/